# Implementing a basic FIFO queue in Java

Tags: java

I need to implement a basic FIFO queue of objects. Whats the best built-in class for do that?

Comment: Can you explain why you need implement a basic FIFO unless this is homework? Why not use on of the many builtin implementations?

Comment: Because i just need add items at the tail and consume it from the head. Jus wondered if there is a basic build in implementation and java.util.Queue works nice

Comment: Queue is the interface, another useful one is Deque, LinkedList is the simplest implementation.  You can also add to the head and consume from the tail if you wish. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the JavaDoc for the [java.util.Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface and pick an appropriate implementing class from the list shown.

Answer (score 8):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is as good as any for just basic FIFO operations, but there are others there that implement the Queue interface in case you need something more advanced.

Comment: Don't forget to declare your LinkedList (the most simple to use, IMHO) as a Queue and not as a List if you have (as me) this bad habit. Else, you will be given access only to the List Interface methods.